# Routing in matdialog in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-material, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to add **routing** to a **Angular Material Mat Dialog in angular**. But there is an problem occurring.

When I try to **add the route URL manually** from

```
https://localhost:3200
```

to

```
https://localhost:3200/login
```

or

```
https://localhost:3200/signin
```

it don't pop up

> **Tab Switching Problem**

Also, There is another problem that when the dialog is opened for login and then if i tab switch to SignIn
there is no change in URL

Navbar.component.ts ( Dialog Initializing Component )

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {


  flag: boolean;
  currentDialog: MatDialogRef<any> = null;

  //Dialog init
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {

   }

  openDialog(tabvalue: number) {

    console.log(tabvalue);
    this.currentDialog = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      data: {tabvalue},
    });

    this.currentDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}

//  dialog.component.ts 
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog.component.html',
})

export class DialogComponent {
  tabs = ['Login', 'Sign in'];

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  // tabvalue have only two values 0 -> tabs[0] -> Login and 1 -> tabs[1] -> SignIn
  selected = this.data.tabvalue
}
```

Navbar.component.html ( template for above code )

```
<mat-toolbar mat-toolbar [routerLink]="['/']">

    <button mat-icon-button (click)="flag = !flag ; value()">

        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <a class="a-menu">
        <h1 class="h1-menu">Notes</h1>
    </a>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/login"  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openDialog(0)">Login</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/signin" routerLinkActive="active"  (click)="openDialog(1)">Sign In</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<!--app-navbar (valueChange)='sb.toggleCustom($event)'></app-navbar-->
<!--this is nothing-->

<app-sidebar [flag]="flag"></app-sidebar>
```

Dialog.component.html ( template for dialog )

```
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">


    <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected">
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
            <app-login *ngIf="tab == 'Login'"></app-login>
            <app-signin *ngIf="tab == 'Sign in'"></app-signin>
        </mat-tab>
        
    </mat-tab-group>


</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>{{selected == 0 ? 'Login' : 'Sign In'}}</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/form-field';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // CLI imports router
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent, DialogComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavbarComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: NavbarComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component: NavbarComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
]; // sets up routes constant where you define your routes

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    DialogComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    MainComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)


  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'fill' } },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Default View

[image: Default View]

On Click Login

[image: Dialog Box Opened for Login]

Manually Typing URL

[image: Manually Typing https://localhost:3200/login]

Output (without Dialog Box pop Up But **URL changed**)

[image: Normal View No change]

Comment: You are requesting to open dialog box from Navbar.component.ts through this.dialog.open(). When you enter url, it is not triggering openDialog function in navbar.compoent.ts. That is the reason it is not opening dialog box when you enter url. And my suggestion to you is not to change url every time you change tab. Try making it single page  application and change url only when user logs in.

Comment: I know that openDialog function is not triggering But why it's not triggering that is what i want to know

Comment: Which component are you redirecting that url to? Did you add something in routes.ts?

Comment: DialogComponent

Comment: Add your dialog component in routes.ts if you haven't. And remember, even after adding it in routes you will not get pop up. It'll render dialog component on your page.

Comment: why, I linked login button with OpenDialog() when i call the route login. OpenDialog should be triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218195/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-and-maruthi-eranki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import and declare the dialog component in "declarations" section. Then add the property "entryComponents" with the dialog component in "app.module.ts" file.

```
import { YourDialog} from './modules/YourDialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...., YourDialog], 
  entryComponents: [YourDialog,]
})
```

Comment: Install angular material and and add "deeppurple-amber.css" in angular.json, under "styles" attribute.
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
            ]